# conditional operator not working well somewhere in MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a cshtml file, I have a table with rows like

```
<td>@lic.Dealer == null ? @String.Empty : @lic.Dealer.Name</td>
```

However, when running, the run time keeps throwing exception complaning NullObjectReferenceException on @lic.Dealer.Name since Dealer is null.

So I had to use

```
var dealerName = @lic.Dealer == null ? @String.Empty : @lic.Dealer.Name;


<td>@dealerName</td>
```

I just wonder why the first piece code does not work well with the conditional operator?

I am using MVC5.

Comment: If you were getting a `NullReferenceException` it was because `lic` was `null` (not because `Dealer` was `null`)

Comment: lic is not null definitely by design and by what shown in debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`Dealer` is indeed null.**

You forgot to wrap your statement in parentheses.

When you write this code:

```
<td>@lic.Dealer == null ? @String.Empty : @lic.Dealer.Name</td>
```

Razor does not view this as a whole statement. Instead, it tries to call `ToString()` on `lic.Dealer` because it thinks that `@lic.Dealer` is trying to output Dealer.

Wrap your code in parentheses, like this:

```
<td>@(lic.Dealer == null ? String.Empty : lic.Dealer.Name)</td>
```

Comment: yes, a good lesson to learn about the behavior of razor in different places.